# String gets separated into different rows in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am currently working on an input file and I do have a column which contains 3 different values in one cell itself. Although this data is not being used in the transformation , I need to input this data from the source and then ignore when it is loaded into the staging table.
But the issue I face is that it gets loaded into separate rows rather than 1 cell.
[image: Sample data cell]

This particular column is input as a string datatype. what change do I need to make to resolve this issue. Please let me know If more details are needed to answer the question.

[image: Flatfile connection setup]

I have uploaded a sample file to google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/17hn8xmRd4CWsgKBzHgdwnR9W4jTJ9lTn/view?usp=sharing

The following is a screenshot of the csv data as opened in a text editor

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have one column which also contains the delimiter.  Is that right and would you be able to provide a sample row, what it looks like in the flat file?

Comment: I assume? that the row with -2.70% 0.0008% etc are the troublesome fields? If not, which row is in question? How does the data look when it arrives in the database? You're showing Excel here, is the file actually Excel (.xls or .xlsx) or Excel compatible data (.csv, .txt, etc)? A different way of asking that - do you use the Excel Source or a Flat FIle Source for this data? If Flat File, add screenshots of how you have the Flat File Connection Manager configured: General screenshot and the Columns tab, please

Comment: @billinkc yes you are right. it is that column which gives me the error.The file is already in the csv  format. We have the csv format which will be loaded into the ssis in the flatfile connection manager.I will add the configuration screenshot.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz. Sorry for the delay.was trying to solve it and got stuck with other projects. I am attaching the link to the sample file. could you please check and see if you can resolve it.thanks. 
         
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17hn8xmRd4CWsgKBzHgdwnR9W4jTJ9lTn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AjayAshok can you confirm that row delimiter is CRLF?  In the sample file, `Estimated Internal Cost Impact` and `Reference Bill` both have only LF in the data, so by default the flat file connection reads it in without the issues noted in your question.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz, the row de-limiter is CRLF but for the columns is comma. what should be followed?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz, the file that I had sent you is the edited version , where for those two affected columns , I had placed quotes to temporarily resolve the issue and that is the reason those two columns have LF in the row -delimiter.  In the un edited version it is 'comma'.

Comment: If you're saying that `Estimated Internal Cost Impact` has commas where the LF's are in the sample file, then I would see about creating the file with a different delimiter like a pipe or maybe quoted identifiers

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz ,yes , it is commas for the 'Estimated Internal Cost Impact'. Could you explain how would I go with the other options? ie how to use a quoted identifier?

Comment: Instead of using a comma delimiter, you might use a tab or pipe.  Or you can try wrapping each column in quotes.  The connection manager can strip these out when reading the file in

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz,thanks. but wrapping each column in quotes could be done automatically by adding in the setting?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to look at the tool you are using to export the data, but this is a common setting and should be something that you can just turn on.

Answer (score 0):

Having downloaded sample.csv from your link, the first thing I did was open it in a text editor (Notepad++, TextPad, Visual Studio, etc) and just looked at what you have.

- Row 1 is column headers
- Encoded in UFT-8 with BOM (byte order marker)
- Line Endings are CR/LF (Carriage Return & Line Feed)
- Column delimiter appears to be a comma `,`
- Double Quote, `"`, is used as the text qualifier but *only* when needed
- There are CR/LF characters in the actual data

I then define my flat file connection manager based on that data

[image]

Finally, I have a data flow with a Flat File Source to a Derived Column and drop a Data Viewer between them

[image]

As you can see, configuring your Flat File Connection Manager as I show will allow all the data to flow into your table as expected.

What is happening now is the CRLF, which is our row delimiter, is having precedence over the embedded CRLF in the column data. By setting the double quote as the Text Qualifier, the data reader correctly "skips" the embedded CRLF until it is encountered outside of the quotes.

Comment: @bilinkc,  I had set the same setting in the flatfile connection manager, but when I load the csv file , the data does not get into the same column as needed. What else could go wrong?

Comment: Did you use the same sample file you provided or are you working with your real/full csv?

Comment: @bilinkc, no, it is the edited version with a few rows removed. But when I load the sample file, it gets loaded in correctly but not the original file.

Comment: As we both get the same results with the sample file, I would encourage you to open the offending original file in a good text editor (TextPad, NotePad++, VS Code) where you can see the original data. Specifically, if you've trimmed some rows that aren't present in the sample, they are likely the offending rows.

Comment: @bilinkc, thanks for the reply. I had tried that earlier.It seems to be the same as the sample csv format. But some how when it is loaded in it gets changed. need to figure out what goes wrong.